# How to reach Hängeseilbrücke Geierlay by using a Schönes Wochenende pass?

Tags: trains, germany, sightseeing, deutsche-bahn

I would like to have a one day visit of the [Geierlay Footbridge](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geierlay) (Fußgängerseilbrücke, don't know the English word for it).

We are a group of 5 people who would like to visit it on a weekend using only local transport from Stuttgart (or preferably from Friedrichshafen but the group joins in Stuttgart). I searched online in Deutsche Bahn for a connection but it does not give any connections with the above mentioned parameters. I searched for a connection to Mörsdorf.

Is there anybody who has done it already or could anybody tell me why DB does not support this? It provides connections on weekdays.

I know I am not allowed to request to plan itineraries using this forum but any pointers on how I could undertake this trip on a weekend using Regionalverkehr would be nice to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DB route planner does not find any connections on Saturday or Sunday because the only bus going to Mörsdorf ([RMV's line 634](http://www.vrminfo.de/fileadmin/data/pdf/fahrplanbuecher/2017/634.pdf)) only operates Monday through Friday.

The closest you can get by public transport during the weekend seem to be by bus to Kastellaun, some 9km from Mörsdorf. From Kastellaun, you would either have to walk (1.5 to 2 hours) or take a taxi. There are several taxi companies in the area, so getting a taxi should not be a problem.

The Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket is however *not* valid on the RMV buses, but only on local and regional trains.

I also hope, that you don't plan to do this on one day? The first connection with only regional trains from Friedrichshafen via Stuttgart to Kastellaun arrives 14:44, while the last connection from Kastellaun via Stuttgart back to Friedrichshafen departs 15:35.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like we need to rent a car. Such a pity that a potentially great tourist attraction does not yet have good public transport systems

Comment: The bridge is part of the Saar-Hunsrück-Steig hiking trail and I assume that most visitors simply walk or hike there instead of going by public transport. As Mörsdorf is a municipality with only 600 inhabitants, I do not find it particularly odd that you can only get there by public transport on weekdays.

Answer (score 2):

The only way would be to take the train to Koblenz, and then take the bus from there, which takes approx. 2,5 hours. I found the bus connection only on www.vrminfo.de, so it's possible, that the Schöne-Wochenend-Ticket is not valid there, thus it's not found by bahn.de. Honestly, if you really want to do that, i'd suggest to take the train to Koblenz and then take a rental car from there.

Comment: What takes 2,5 hours? The bus from Koblenz to Mörsfeld takes about 1,5 hours, but coming from Friedrichshafen/Stuttgart, it seems more reasonable to take the bus from Mainz instead. Using only regional trains, the entire trip will take 8-9 hours and as I wrote in my answer, the bus to Mörsfeld does not operate on weekends, or did you manage to find any other bus, but line 634?

Comment: You're right, vrminfo.de tricked me. Though the journey time with the bus depends on the time of the day. I see only one connection at 12:10, which takes 1:25 hours, other connections take more time.